# Ansible Python3 API, multi threaded app failing on connecting

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, ansible

I'm writting a multi-threaded app that calls Ansible by Python API.

Is the Asible Python API thread safe? How to make independent CLIARGS in each thread?

Now, in each thread I initialize context.CLIARGS if connection is going to be by ssh or winrm.

It seems that in some cases when threads are running in parallel, ansbile starts playbook with ssh connection and then switches to winrm -with a default port.

I receive an error:

```
{'results': [{'unreachable': True
'msg': "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='server.test.com'
port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02d0d3c198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))"
```

which is strange because it should go via ssh. And even if this would ever go via winrm I never set a port to 5986 but to 5985.

My code snippet:

```
  # initialize needed objects
  loader = DataLoader() # Takes care of finding and reading yaml, json and ini files

  if os_type == 'linux':
    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=(hostname+',') ) #sources=('/xxx/inventory_file',)) #< put HOSTNAME

    conn_type='ssh'

    variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory, version_info=CLI.version_info(gitinfo=False))

    # since the API is constructed for CLI it expects certain options to always be set in the context object
    context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection=conn_type,
                    module_path=None, forks=10, remote_user=ansible_user, private_key_file=None, ansible_ssh_pass=ansible_ssh_pass,
                    ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=None,
                    become_method=None, become_user=None, verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None, diff=False)

  elif os_type == 'windows': # this is a special case, when we detected windows, we set inventory(for auth) and conn_type
    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=(inventory_file) ) #sources=('/xxx/inventory_file',)) #< put HOSTNAME 

    conn_type ='winrm'
    ansible_connection='winrm'
    ansible_port = 5985
    ansible_winrm_transport='ntlm'

    variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory, version_info=CLI.version_info(gitinfo=False))

    # since the API is constructed for CLI it expects certain options to always be set in the context object
    context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, 
                    connection=conn_type, ansible_connection=ansible_connection, ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation='ignore', ansible_user=ansible_user,
                    module_path=None, forks=10, remote_user=ansible_user, private_key_file=None,
                    ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=None,
                    become_method=None, become_user=None, verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None, diff=False,
                    ansible_port=ansible_port, ansible_winrm_transport=ansible_winrm_transport
                   )

  try:

    pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, passwords=passwords)

    results = pbex.run()
```

Environment:

```
RHEL 7.8
Python 3.6.9
ansible==2.9.6
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.1
cryptography==2.9
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Threads==0.0.1a0
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
ntlm-auth==1.4.0
pycparser==2.20
pywinrm==0.4.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-ntlm==1.1.0
six==1.14.0
urllib3==1.25.9
waitress==1.4.3
Werkzeug==1.0.1
xmltodict==0.12.0
```